# Unable to connect to socket in docker: PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, scapy

I have an application I am trying to move into a docker container. I have most things working, but the part of the application that requires elevated privileges (to use socket and configure network parameters) does not seem to be working.

What I've tried:

- Giving the `--privileged` flag
- Giving the `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN` flag
- Removing security options with `--security-opt apparmor=unconfined --security-opt seccomp=unconfined`
- Adding user groups and sudo in the Dockerfile
- Using the `--net=host \` option.
- Adding my user to the docker group
- Giving the `--cap-add=SYS_RAWIO` flag
- Adding my user to the netdev group in the Dockerfile `RUN groupadd -r netdev && usermod -a -G netdev $USER`

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/app/support_files/wizard_configuration_routines.py", line 781, in find_device
    device_list = scan_subnet('192.168.30.0/24',g_interface)
  File "/app/support_files/wizard_configuration_routines.py", line 757, in scan_subnet
    answered, unanswered = scapy.arping(subnet,verbose=False,iface=g_interface)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scapy/layers/l2.py", line 890, in arping
    ans, unans = srp(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 687, in srp
    s = iface.l2socket()(promisc=promisc, iface=iface,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scapy/arch/linux.py", line 484, in __init__
    self.ins = socket.socket(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 232, in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Below are the relevant files

Dockerfile

```
# Slim version of Python
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Download Package Information
RUN apt update -y

# Install Tkinter
RUN apt install tk -y

# Install fontconfig
RUN apt install fontconfig -y

# Install Pillow
RUN python3 -m pip install Pillow
RUN python3 -m pip install ouster-sdk
RUN python3 -m pip install scapy
RUN python3 -m pip install customtkinter
RUN apt install net-tools -y
RUN fc-cache -f -v

# Commands to run Tkinter application
CMD ["/app/SCOT_wizard.py"]
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
```

build.sh

```
sudo docker build -t tkinter_in_docker .
```

run.sh

```
sudo docker run -u=$(id -u $USER):$(id -g $USER) \
 -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw \
 -v $(pwd)/app:/app \
 -v $(pwd)/logs:/logs \
 -v $(pwd)/records:/records \
 -v $(pwd)/fonts:/.fonts\
 -w /app \
 --privileged \
 --net=host \
 --rm \
  tkinter_in_docker
```

In an attempt to understand the problem, I made a simple docker container that has the line that is failing, and it works. I can't figure out why it won't work in the larger application. Here is the minimum example:

Dockerfile

```
# Slim version of Python
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Download Package Information
RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install net-tools -y
RUN apt install -y libpcap0.8 

RUN python3 -m pip install scapy
# Commands to run Tkinter application
CMD ["SCOT_wizard.py"]
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
```

run.sh

```
sudo docker run \
 -v $(pwd)/app:/app \
 -w /app \
 --net=host \
 --rm \
  tkinter_in_docker
```

/app/SCOT_wizard.py

```
import scapy.all as scapy
answered, unanswered = scapy.arping('192.168.11.0/24',verbose=False,iface='eno2')
print(answered)
```

Comment: This seems to be getting no traction. Is there anything I can add to make this more understandable? This problem doesn't seem to come up very often, but it seems pretty important. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, just not sure what yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution online that lets me get x-server to work while root. This solves my problem, but I am open to a better way to get this to work without having to run a command on the host machine.

Command in question and [source](https://forums.docker.com/t/start-a-gui-application-as-root-in-a-ubuntu-container/17069). Run this command on the Docker host machine.

`xhost +local:docker`

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the container as root. To do that you can either add to Dockerfile the line:

```
USER root
```

or run rhe container with the -u parameter:

```
docker run -u root <image-name>
```

Comment: `USER root` still has the same error, and `docker run -u root` messes up the X server forwarding that I'm using to see the application. Is there another way to get the process to run with the needed permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Your minimal example seems to work because you are not trying to run it as a specific user using the `-u` option. In your main application, you are setting the user of the container to the same user as your host system with `-u=$(id -u $USER):$(id -g $USER)`. That could be why your main application does not have enough privileges, but your minimal example does.

> `USER root` still has the same error, and `docker run -u root` messes up the X server forwarding that I'm using to see the application.
> Is there another way to get the process to run with the needed permissions?

Since running your container with a user `root` does not work, make sure that user has the necessary permissions inside the container. That might involve adding the user to specific groups that have access to raw sockets.
For example, you can add the user to the `netdev` group ([mentioned here](https://superuser.com/q/1148322/141)) inside the container, but remember, this group might not exist in a slim container.

```
RUN groupadd -r netdev && usermod -a -G netdev $USER
```

Do replace `$USER` with the username you are using, or use some [Docker `ARGS`](https://docs.docker.com/build/guide/build-args/) to make it dynamic.
See also "**[Running Docker Containers as a Non-root User with a Custom UID / GID](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/running-docker-containers-as-a-non-root-user-with-a-custom-uid-and-gid)**" by [Nick Janetakis](https://www.youtube.com/@NickJanetakis/about).

Along with `NET_ADMIN`, the raw socket operation might require [`SYS_RAWIO` capability](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities), to "Perform I/O port operations (`iopl(2)` and `ioperm(2)`)".
Add it with the `--cap-add=SYS_RAWIO` flag in your `run.sh`.

---

The OP's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76821485/6309) allows any local user to connect to your X server, which is why the OP is able to use X forwarding even when running as the `root` user in the Docker container.

However, be aware that using `xhost +local:docker` can pose security risks. It essentially opens up your X server to any local user. If you have any malicious software running as a local user on your machine, it could potentially spy on your X server interactions.

If you are interested in more secure alternatives, you could:

- **Either use Xauth**: That is a more secure approach than `xhost` as it relies on magic cookies. The general idea is to mount the `.Xauthority` file or folder into your container and ensure the `DISPLAY` environment variable is set correctly:

  ```bash
  sudo docker run -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v $HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:ro ...
  ```

  Make sure the Docker container user has the correct permissions to access the `.Xauthority` file.
- **Or use a specific X server for Docker**: Another approach is to run a separate X server instance specifically for your Docker containers. That can be achieved using tools like [`Xephyr`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xephyr), which lets you run a nested X server.

  Start `Xephyr`:

  ```bash
  Xephyr -ac -br -noreset -screen 800x600 :1
  ```

  Then, run your container with:

  ```bash
  DISPLAY=:1 sudo docker run ...
  ```

  That way, your Docker applications use a separate X server instance, isolating them from your main X session.
- **Or use GUI-based Docker tools**: There are tools and platforms like [X11Docker](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker) which allow running GUI-based Docker containers securely. These tools often handle X server permissions, GPU acceleration, etc., without the need for manual configurations.

If you can avoid `xhost +local:docker` for production or critical environments, it would be more secure. The alternatives might require more setup initially but can offer better isolation and security.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It seems you are correct that changing the user was the cause of my issues, but unfortunately, your suggestions didn't fix the issue. I'll be modifying my question to reflect that I attempted your suggestion. Your advice did lead me to a solution that seems to be working for me, even though it's not ideal. In light of this I will reward you the bounty if there are no better solutions posted. Thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: @Zico OK, thank you for the feedback. I have edited the answer to proposes more secure alternatives to your current solution.